# Odata service - entity's data not showing up in browser

Tags: odata

I am new to Odata services. i have included the ADO.net entity model successfully and in the designer class, i have changed the  EntitySetRights propert to All. the webservice is being accessed successfully in the browser with the url http://localhost:4245/WcfDataService1.svc but when i try to access the individual table ("collections", in my case), i do not get the propertis displayed.
all i get is this

collections

Sunday, April 22, 2012 3:46 AM
Sunday, April 22, 2012 3:46 AM

there are a total of two records in the table right now.
Kindly tell me what to do so that the records are displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior depends on the actual browser you use. If it's IE you will se so called "Feed view" since the payload is a valid ATOM feed. To see the underlying raw XML go to Internet Options -> Content -> Feeds and Web Slices Settings and uncheck the "Turn on feed reading view". Then restart the browser, you should see the raw XML from the service.

Comment: yeah it worked on IE. thanks!... can you tell me how can i do that on Firefox?

Comment: This is useful when viewing Odata records from Microsoft CRM via http://<CRM URL>/<CRM Org Name>/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SalesOrderDetailSet

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a browser, I'd recommend looking at Fiddler for testing ad-hoc OData requests. Fiddler allows you to manipulate request headers to get responses in Atom or JSON, specify headers we recommend (like MaxDataServiceVersion), etc.

I wrote up a basic post about using Fiddler to access OData; maybe it would help: http://www.bitwhys.com/odata-101-constructing-http-requests-with-fiddler/.